# css stretch li based on content

Tags: html, css, html-lists, stretch

I have [this code here](http://jsfiddle.net/TEXPQ/) and I am trying to make the `ul.submenu li` to stretch according to its contents. As you can see, the 3rd `li` of the `ul.submenu` has a long text which hides instead of stretching the `li`.

I have tried changing the `display` property of all elements on the DOM with various combinations but I cannot get it right.

What am I doing wrong and why this happens? What am I missing?

Any help will be very much appreciated! :)

Comment: your submenu is absolute positioned and that means it has a fixed size. your min-width of 160 sets it initially to that width and then it stays that way. When you want to auto-adjust the measurements of absolute positioned elements the solution would be javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir. Still though, changing the `position` of the `ul.submenu` to `relative` gives me the same result. The `li` doesn't stretch.

Comment: OK, let me say it in other words. You use a block-element, that has a position other than static. That means the sizes of that container are fixed an can't be automatically adjusted in a dynamically way by the document. What you could do is using a script that figures out the width of the longest li and according to that set the width for the ul.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently the text has little bearing on the layout, because of block display and absolute positioning.

You can change this by giving the `li`s `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`. I've [forked an example](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/mTKKM/) where the sub-menu is as long as the longest item requires.

#### Explanation

`inline-block` gives the element properties of `inline` and `block` display: `inline` in that the element should flow like text, and take its initial layout and dimensions from the text it contains. But the `block` part means you can also specify top and bottom padding and margin, clears, etc. Even with this set, the containing element is still absolutely positioned (most text content just flows as long as it needs because normally the containing block element fills 100% width - not the case for absolute, relative and fixed elements), so its instinct is to collapse to the minimum width, that of the first word. But if we use `white-space: nowrap`, we can force the text to extend as much as it needs, so the full sentence is used as the measure.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much for the correct and quick reply! :)

Comment: NP. Realise the answer didn't really explain how it worked, so I updated it.

Answer (score -1):

You could just change the min-width to:

```
min-width: 240px;
```

[View Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TEXPQ/5/)